# Train selective branch of multi output keras model

Tags: keras

I have a multi output Keras model with a structure resembling this:

```
s = some_shared_layers()(input)
non_trainable1 = Dense(trainable=False) (s) 
non_trainable2 = Dense(trainable=False) (s) 
trainable = Dense() (s) 

model = Model(input, outputs=[non_trainable1, non_trainable2, trainable])
```

My model first computes a forward pass and uses the 1st 2 outputs to manipulate the input. It then computes another forward pass to get the 3rd  output.

```
out1, out2,_ =model.predict(input_data) 
processed_data = foo(input_data, out1, out2) 
_,_, out3 = model.predict(processed_data)
```

How should I call `model.fit()` to train only the `trainable` layer? If I exclude the losses for the other outputs, Keras warns `we will not be expecting any data to be passed to "non_trainable1" during training` and excludes them from the computational graph.

Is there a better way to structure the model for this task?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it correctly, you simply don't need those layers, and in fact you should have two models, one for predicting only, the other for training.

**Non trainable:**

```
model1 = Model(input, [non_trainable1, non_trainable2])
#model 1 doesn't need to be compiled, since you won't train it
```

**Trainable:**

```
model2 = Model(input, trainable)
model2.compile(loss=onlyTheLossForTrainable)
```

**Using them:**

```
out1, out2 =model1.predict(input_data) 
processed_data = foo(input_data, out1, out2) 

model2.fit(processed_data, expected_outputs, ....)
```

Comment: I am currently using that as a workaround and it works if I run the code as you have described. But if I try to use the processing function `foo` in more complex ways -- say inside a `ImageDataGenerator` -- then `model2.fit_generator()` raises a `ValueError: Tensor "non_trainable1" is not an element of this graph.`

Comment: Why inside a generator?? And what exactly are you trying to do inside the generator? It sounds you're using a tensor instead of using predict.

Comment: I'm working with images and am using the generator for data augmentation. As a naive first attempt, I tried to pass `foo` as the `preprocessing_function` argument (ref [docs](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/) ).  `foo` takes an image, calls `model1.predict()` and returns an edited image.